# "Enter parameter value" on access query issue

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to run an access SELECT query through a button on a subform. I need to use one of the fields in the subform as criteria for the query. I currently have this:

```
SELECT id, issue, complaint, action, reviewer, ticket
FROM tblEscalations
WHERE asin = Forms![form_name]![subform_name].[id];
```

Every time I run the query, I get the pop up asking for a parameter value for `WHERE asin = Forms![form_name]![subform_name].[id];`. Can you please tell me what's wrong with this?

I've only been doing Access for like a month and a half so the the answer might be very simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you refer to a control which is contained on a subform, you must reference it via the name of the subform control rather than the name of the form which is contained in the subform control.

And the subform control name can be different than the name of the form which it contains.

Since `Forms![form_name]![subform_name].[id]` isn't working, `subform_name` may be the name of the form.  You need to substitute the name of the subform *control*:

```vb
Forms!form_name!YourSubformControl!id
```

When you have that name correct, running this statement in the Immediate window will tell you *"SubForm"*:

```vb
? TypeName(Forms!form_name!YourSubformControl!id)
```

Here is an Immediate window session on my system with a form named *frmParent* which includes a subform control named *Child2*.  And that control contains a form named *fsubColortable* which in turn contains a text box named *ID*:

```vb
? TypeName(Forms!frmParent!Child2)
SubForm
? Forms!frmParent!Child2.Form.Name
fsubColortable
? Forms!frmParent!Child2!ID
 1
```

If you're not familiar with the Immediate window, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>.  Then type this in the window and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```vb
? Forms.Count
```

That should be enough to get you started.  :-)